# Way to change xargs arguments to include a flag per argument?

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, xargs

I have some passing experience with xargs, but I don't quite know how to do this:

- I have a list of archives retrieved from tarsnap using `tarsnap --list-archives`
- I want to delete all archives from a certain day (there are 24 made each day)

I can use xargs to accomplish this:

```
tarsnap --list-archives | grep 2014-06-09 | xargs -n 1 tarsnap -df
```

However this runs tarsnap over and over again with one argument at a time (which is expected):

```
tarsnap -df 2014-06-09-00
tarsnap -df 2014-06-09-01
tarsnap -df 2014-06-09-02
... etc ...
```

The tarsnap documentation states that you can delete multiple archives by passing in multiple `-f` flags:

```
tarsnap -d -f 2014-06-09-00 -f 2014-06-09-01 -f 2014-06-09-02 # ... and so on
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with xargs?

(Aside: It might be pointless to even do this, since I have a feeling running tarsnap with multiple `-f` flags just causes tarsnap to run itself multiple times, one argument at a time... but I could be wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the idea quite similar to @choroba's, you can get rid of `grep` altogether and use `sed` instead:

```
tarsnap --list-archives | sed -n '/2014-06-09/s/^/-f /p' | xargs tarsnap -d
```

Answer (score 6):

You can actually do this with xargs

```
$ archivelist=$(tarsnap --list-a|xargs -I {} echo "-f {} ")
$ echo $archivelist
-f 2014-06-09-00 -f 2014-06-09-01 -f 2014-06-09-02 -f 2014-06-09-03
```

Answer (score 2):

You can inject `-f` to the list before every item with `sed`:

```
tarsnap --list-archives | grep 2014-06-09 | sed 's/^/-f /' | xargs tarsnap -d
```

Answer (score 0):

If `tarsnap` accepts no space (i.e. -f2014-06-09) you can use GNU Parallel with context replace:

```
tarsnap --list-archives | parallel -Xj1 tarsnap -d -f{}
```